# How to make a widget available after a selection in dropdown?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create a card after a user makes a selection in drop down how to achieve this in flutter. The UI model is given below.

The first card is like a permanent one but the second card should appear after if there is any change in the dropdown button.

The lower card should be scrollable and the size should be dynamic like a listview. if the Key and data increases the value should increase.

The Code I have used for creating the app bar and the 1st card is here.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 75,
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Flutter App',
            style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                textStyle:
                    TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 26)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 250,
              child: Column(children: [
                Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 15),
                          child: Text(
                            'Text here',
                            style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                              fontSize: 37,
                            )),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: Text(
                          'Some text here',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                              textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18)),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                        child: DropdownButton(
                          items: markets
                              .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String val) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                value: val, child: Text(val));
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (sto) {
                            setState(() {
                              _mySelection = sto;
                            });
                            retrievedata.getPrice(_mySelection);
                          },
                          value: _mySelection,
                          hint: Text('Hint text here'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 5,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please provide some code you already have.

Comment: @Akif added the code!

Comment: check this: https://dartpad.dev/7818b6ff4109fe3008309fbda7fc1e34

Comment: @Ashok I don't need dropdown. I need the 2nd card to be rendered after if there is any change in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by having an additional state that is responsible for visibility of second card. Something like this:

```
  final visible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
       ...
             onChanged: (sto) {
                setState(() {
                   _mySelection = sto;
                   visible = true;
             });
            retrievedata.getPrice(_mySelection);
         },
       ...
```

And later on we can make the second card visible based on this value:

```
visible ? SecondCard( 
              ...
          ) : SizedBox.shrink()
```

This ensures that nothing is shown until `visible` is set to `true`

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `Card` that should appear after dropDownChanges to `Visibility` widget.

Add this variable

```
bool _isVisible = false;
```

Make changes to DropdownButton

```
DropdownButton(
  ...
  onChanged: (sto) {
    setState(() {
      _mySelection = sto;
      _isVisible = true;
    });
     retrievedata.getPrice(_mySelection);
  },
  ...
),
```

Wrap the `Card` with `Visiblity`

```
Visibility (
  visible: _isVisible,
  child: Card(
    child: ....
  ),
),
```

If you want the card to be always visible and enable interaction only after the `DropdownButton` changes, wrap the card to `IgnorePointer` instead of visibility.